# Android says that I support all the languages when is not true

Tags: android, android-manifest, localizable.strings

I have two apps, and I run the aapt command to see the AndroidManifest info, it says that my app is supported in all the languages

Meanwhile with the other app it only says the languages that I defined a folder for it.

Both has the same folders:

```
   res/
   - values
   - values-en
   - values-es
```

But with one the supported languages are all and the other just English and Español

Why is this happening?

Comment: Can it be that if I have imported the google play services lib detects that it's supported in the languages of this lib?